# merging two data frames by column, but only one column in R

Tags: r

I have two data frames of this form:

A

```
code  population index
1        400       5
...
```

B

```
code  rate index
1      50    5
...
```

I want to merge B in A by code, but I want only to ***merge rate***.
Expected output:

C

```
code  population  rate  index
1      400         50     5
...
```

How to do that in R?

Comment: Do you want to merge on `code` or `index`? (It's hard to tell because they are the same in your sample data, so merging on one or both is the same).

Comment: But the general answer is subset the columns from `B` that you want to merge, e.g., `merge(A, B)` merges `rate` based on `code` and `index` (all common columns); `merge(A, B[c("code", "rate")])` merges `rate` based on `code` - we dropped `index` from `B` before the merge.

Comment: A %>% inner_join(B %>% select(1,2)) using dplyr

Comment: @GregorThomas I just want to merge B column "rate" in A based on code not index.

Comment: @GregorThomas Your solution works. Thanks

Comment: @KarthikS Thanks, it s a good one too.

Comment: @KarthikS , actually yours works and Gregor's one not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `dplyr`. Here is some information on how to provide a proper [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

df_a <- tibble(
  code = 1,
  population = 400,
  index = 5
)

df_b <- tibble(
  code = 1,
  rate = 50,
  index = 5
)

df_a %>% 
  inner_join(df_b, by = "code") %>% 
  select(code, population, rate, index.x) %>% 
  rename(index = index.x)

#> # A tibble: 1 x 4
#>    code population  rate index
#>   <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1        400    50     5
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Ok, but @Gregor Thomas answer is the simplest: merge(A, B[c("code", "rate")])